# Controller $scope attribute does not update (socket connection)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I want to have my angular controllers get updated by factories connected with websockets.

**Factory:**

```
function($rootScope, mySocketFactory) {
    mySocketFactory.setHandler('message', function(event) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            Factory.msg = event.data;
        });
        console.log('factory', Factory.msg);
    });

    var Factory = {};
    Factory.msg = 'init';
    return Factory;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function ($scope, myFactory) {
    console.log(myFactory.msg);

    $scope.msg = myFactory.msg;
}
```

**Partial:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="StatusBarController" class="col-lg-12">
    {{msg}}
</div>
```

If the factory gets data via the `message` event `console.log('factory', Factory.msg);` returns the updated value, but the controller does not apply the change and stick to the `init` data. What am I doing wrong here?

***Note:*** I tried the same example with an array instead of a string and it worked!? First I thought it could be because strings are not passed by reference but since we are in the JS world they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding a property, you could create a `getter` function form factory which will return `msg` property value, the `{{msg()}}` on html will get evaluated on each digest cycle, as you ran it from your service whenever you are receiving `message`.

**Factory**

```
var Factory = {};
Factory.getMsg = function(){
     return Factory.msg;
};
return Factory;
```

**controller**

```
function ($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.msg = myFactory.getMsg;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="StatusBarController" class="col-lg-12">
    {{msg()}}
</div>
```

**Update**

Rather than the above way I'd suggest you to follow `dot rule`, that will need to declare `object` and that object will have hold on properties Factory.data = {msg : 'init'};` . Once you update the factory variable it will automatically update its reference in your controller variable.

**Factory**

```
function($rootScope, mySocketFactory) {
    mySocketFactory.setHandler('message', function(event) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            Factory.data.msg = event.data;
        });
        console.log('factory', Factory.msg);
    });

    var Factory = {};
    Factory.data = { msg : 'init'};
    return Factory;
}
```

**controller**

```
function ($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.info = myFactory.data;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="StatusBarController" class="col-lg-12">
    {{info.msg}}
</div>
```

Comment: That works fine. So the trick is to use a function in the html partial? Is that the 'standard way' to do such kind of things? I'm quite new in the angular world.

Comment: But more important why does it work with an array without having a getter?

Comment: @messy look at my edit..the updated answer is the correct one & good  practice to have it..

Comment: That works well, but still one question is open for me. Why does it work with an object/array but not with a string?

Comment: Primitive datatypes doesn't work with there references..as object/array does